# Changing time format in Ubuntu

Tags: time

The time in my Ubuntu desktop is shown as "May 20 08:05". Could I change it as "May 20 08.05"? That is because I live in Finland and I would like to time to be shown as in Finland.

Answer (score 0):

`dconf-editor` will allow you to change the format of time in the Panel. When you launch it, the Configuration Editor will appear. Click in the left side on 
**com** | **canonical** | **indicator** | **datetime** 
and then on the right change the value of **customer-time-format** from **%d %b** to **%d.%b**.